# how to prevent data from being repeated in the template even though the context is being nested

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to implement an upvote and downvote functionality in my website. I am getting the data in two's and i think this reason is because the `suppliers_votes_count` is being nested in the `suppliers` data cominf from the view. How can I avoid this please.

This is an image that shows the template[image]

And a proof for this is that if i print the result outside of the loop, it works normally.

To understand the question better, check the view-supplier.html, you will t=see this `{% for vote in suppliers_votes_count %}` being nested in this `{% for supplier in suppliers %}`. I think this is what causes that.

views.py

```
def Viewsupplier(request):
    title = "All Suppliers"
    suppliers = User.objects.filter(user_type__is_supplier=True)

    # Get the updated count:
    suppliers_votes_count = {}
    for supplier in suppliers:
        upvote_count = supplier.upvotes
        downvote_count = supplier.downvotes
        supplier_count = {supplier: {'upvote': upvote_count, 'downvote': downvote_count } }
        suppliers_votes_count.update(supplier_count)

    context = {"suppliers":suppliers, "title":title, "suppliers_votes_count": suppliers_votes_count}
    return render(request, 'core/view-suppliers.html', context)
```

view-suppliers.html

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-data3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for supplier in suppliers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{supplier.email}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="table-data-feature">
                    <a href="{% url 'upvote' supplier.id %}" class="m-r-10">
                        <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Like">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up">&nbsp;
                            {% for vote in suppliers_votes_count %}
                                {{vote.upvotes}}
                            {% endfor %}
                        &nbsp;</i></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{% url 'downvote' supplier.id %}">
                        <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Dislike">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-down">&nbsp;
                            {% for vote in suppliers_votes_count %}
                                {{vote.downvotes}}
                            {% endfor %}
                        &nbsp;</i></button>
                    </a>
                </div>                                                  
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
            <tr><td class="text-center p-5" colspan="7"><h4>No supplier available</h4></td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to offer to combine supplier data and vote counts onto one object and avoid nested loops in the template but then realized that since you can do this in the view

```
upvote_count = supplier.upvotes
downvote_count = supplier.downvotes
```

there is no reason to build, pass and process separately `suppliers_votes_count`

so in the template instead of this

```
{% for vote in suppliers_votes_count %}
   {{vote.upvotes}}
{% endfor %}
```

use this

```
supplier.upvotes
```

similar to downvotes